# Why do i need to define the image of a Label two times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I was watching this tutorial on how to make a pdf_reader:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itRLRfuL_PQ&t=101s

At 7.26 she types this line of code:

```
logo_label.image = logo
```

I was just wondering why, as she says, this line of code is "absolutely necessary", even if the program works without it.

Here is the part of code I'm referring to:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

logo = Image.open("tkinterResources/logo.png")
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
logo_label = tk.Label(image=logo)
logo_label.image = logo
logo_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Comment: It has something to do with the garbage collector of python. Hence, you need to (explicitly) instantiate it again. For a better understanding, check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111190625id_/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @FrainBr33z3 for the answer, it can be found at this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111190625id_/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm).

In case the site disappears, I paste its content below:

> When you add a PhotoImage or other Image object to a Tkinter widget, you must keep your own reference to the image object. If you don’t, the image won’t always show up.
> The problem is that the Tkinter/Tk interface doesn’t handle references to Image objects properly; the Tk widget will hold a reference to the internal object, but Tkinter does not. When Python’s garbage collector discards the Tkinter object, Tkinter tells Tk to release the image. But since the image is in use by a widget, Tk doesn’t destroy it. Not completely. It just blanks the image, making it completely transparent…
> The solution is to make sure to keep a reference to the Tkinter object, for example by attaching it to a widget attribute:

```
photo = PhotoImage(...)

label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack()
```